# div doesn't appear with the appropriate css style

Tags: html, css

I cannot understand why the following div does not appear in the page with the style I have given it in `style.css`.  The header appears just fine, the problem is in the div with `id="navigate"`

```
<div id="navigate">
    <h5>Hello</h5>
</div>
```

which considering the CSS I have used I have expected it to be of width 100%, with a height of 200px and red background but instead only the word "Hello" appears.

```
#navigate {
      height: 200px;
      width: 100%;
      background-color:red;
    }
```

I post the whole code in case it gives a clue

CSS

```css
/* http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/
       v2.0 | 20110126
       License: none (public domain)
    */

html,
body,
div,
span,
applet,
object,
iframe,
h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6,
p,
blockquote,
pre,
a,
abbr,
acronym,
address,
big,
cite,
code,
del,
dfn,
em,
img,
ins,
kbd,
q,
s,
samp,
small,
strike,
strong,
sub,
sup,
tt,
var,
b,
u,
i,
center,
dl,
dt,
dd,
ol,
ul,
li,
fieldset,
form,
label,
legend,
table,
caption,
tbody,
tfoot,
thead,
tr,
th,
td,
article,
aside,
canvas,
details,
embed,
figure,
figcaption,
footer,
header,
hgroup,
menu,
nav,
output,
ruby,
section,
summary,
time,
mark,
audio,
video {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  font-size: 100%;
  font: inherit;
  /*vertical-align: baseline;*/
}


/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */

article,
aside,
details,
figcaption,
figure,
footer,
header,
hgroup,
menu,
nav,
section {
  display: block;
}

body {
  line-height: 1;
}

ol,
ul {
  list-style: none;
}

blockquote,
q {
  quotes: none;
}

blockquote:before,
blockquote:after,
q:before,
q:after {
  content: '';
  content: none;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
}


/* ~~~~~~~~ Global ~~~~~~~~ */

.container {
  /*class*/
  background: #35424a;
  width: 70%;
  /*In order to be responsive we will use percentage*/
  height: 50px;
  margin: auto;
  /*This will move it to the middle wow wow wow*/
  overflow: hidden;
  /*if something goes outside of a div i don't want a scrollbar to appear, i want it
       to be hidden*/
}


/* ~~~~~~~~ Header ~~~~~~~~~~*/

header {
  position: inherit;
  color: #ffffff;
  /* color of text */
  min-height: 30px;
  /*min-height instead of height, that way when it's responsive and the screen is
       smaller and the text grow or the menu goes in the next line we want the high to adjust*/
}

header a {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  float: left;
  padding-top: 5px;
}

header form {
  float: left;
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-left: 5px;
}

#nav-search {
  text-align: center;
  width: 150px;
  height: 30px;
}

header .info {
  display: table-cell;
  padding-left: 100px;
  padding-top: 20px;
}

header h5 {
  display: table-cell;
  padding-left: 20px;
}

header .btn-success {
  float: right;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-80%);
  margin-left: 5px;
}


/* ~~~~~~~~ Navigate ~~~~~~~~~~*/

#navigate {
  height: 200px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <meta name="description" content="Test site">
  <meta name="keywords" content="test, site, whatever">
  <meta name="author" content="Sonam1790">
  <title>Elite Properties</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <div class="container">
      <a href="index.html" class="logo">
        <img src="CSS/small_logo.png" alt="Test Site" />
      </a>
      <form method="GET" action="index.php">
        <input id="nav-search" type="text" name="search" placeholder="Search" />
      </form>
      <div class="info">
        <h5>tel: 123456789</h5>
        <h5>fax: +090 44 12943</h5>
        <h5>email: sonam1790@gmail.com</h5>
      </div>
      <button type="button" class="btn-success">Register</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn-success">Sign in</button>
    </div>
  </header>
  <div id="navigate">
    <h5>Hello</h5>
  </div>
  <footer>
    <p>Test site, Copyright &copy; 2017</p>
  </footer>
</body>
```

Comment: Is `#navigate` declared as anything other than a `block` element for whatever reason? Do you get the intended result if you declare `display: block` to `#navigate`? Another way you can determine if that selector is even applying is to adjust the font color, since this is the only visible part of the element you can currently see, try changing its color to something obvious, like "red". If this rule applies you'll know that your selectors are valid and that the issue probably lies with something else like the display type of the element, or a few additional missing rules of the kind.

Comment: Thats the solution. If i declare display: block to #navigate it works. Thanks a lot i didn't know that display was so important.

Comment: You might want to add `div` to your array of display-role reset rules as well so that you don't have this issue with any other `div`s.

Comment: Done it , thanks for the info

Answer (score 0):

Your h5 style will override the div style in the code you posted. One easy solution is to specify an h5 style for the #navigate div:

```
#navigate h5 {
      height: 200px;
      width: 100%;
      background-color:red;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

next time dont select every single html component u used to give styling to. Just do

```
*, *::before, *::after
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  font-size: 100%;
  font: inherit;
}
```

itll work the same

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).